# Create an web app installation package, that includes "everything"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, installation, web-deployment-project

Would it be possible, with the tools in VS2010, to create an msi-package that includes everything needed, and installed "on demand" for a mvc 3 app?

It should include IIS, SQL-Server Express, .NET 4, and the mvc3 assemblies.

That would be very handy to have to give users a single install-file, regardless if they use xp, vista or 7. The package should autmatically dectect what's missing, and install that.

Answer (score 4):

You can try use a Web Setup Project.

Add a new project to your solution.

In the "Add New Project" dialog, select `Other Project Types->Setup and Deployment->Visual Studio Installer`.

Then select `Web Setup Project`.

In the created setup project, add `Project Output...` (Content Files) to the `Web Application Folder` (in File System Editor).

The web setup project includes by default check for IIS and .NET framework. It is possible to add checks for other dependencies.

When building the setup project, it is created the msi, along with a setup.exe that includes some pre-install validation.

Comment: Thanks awe, i got hint from your answer and after googling i got below link which explain nicely how to create Web Setup Project for asp.net web application. 
http://dataerror.blogspot.in/2010/06/creating-web-setup-project-for-aspnet.html

Comment: What that link does in addition to my description is adding 3 options for deploying different web.config dependent on wat the user selects. You can use this mechanism for other things as well (not just for web.config, and not just for type of environment). If your setup is only targetet at one type of environment, you don't really need that extra step - it will only be annoying when running the setup.